# What is the difference between signing by OpenSSL and Microsoft Cryptography libraries?

Tags: c#, cryptography, openssl, x509certificate, signing

I wrote two methods for signing using RSA and SHA256, the first one with OpenSSL library and the second one with Microsoft Cryptography library.

OpenSSL implementation:

```
    private string PasswordHandler(bool verify, object userdata)
    {
        return userdata.ToString();
    }

    private string Sign(string signParams)
    {
        var privateCertPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\certificate.pem");
        string privateKey;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(privateCertPath))
        {
            privateKey = sr.ReadToEnd();                
        }

        OpenSSL.Crypto.RSA rsa = OpenSSL.Crypto.RSA.FromPrivateKey(new BIO(privateKey), PasswordHandler, _password);
        //hash method
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.SHA1;

        BIO b = new BIO(signParams);
        CryptoKey ck = new CryptoKey(rsa);

        byte[] res1 = MessageDigestContext.Sign(md, b, ck);

        return Uri.EscapeDataString(System.Convert.ToBase64String(res1));
    }
```

Cryptography implementation:

```
    private string Sign(string data)
    {
        var privateCertPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\certificate.pfx");

        X509Certificate2 privateCert = new X509Certificate2(privateCertPath, _password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)privateCert.PrivateKey;
        RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKey1 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        privateKey1.ImportParameters(privateKey.ExportParameters(true));

        // Get the bytes to be signed from the string 
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

        //const string sha256Oid = "2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1";
        //HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
        //byte[] hashBytes = algorithm.ComputeHash(bytes);
        //byte[] signature = privateKey1.SignHash(hashBytes, sha256Oid);

        byte[] signature = privateKey1.SignData(bytes, "SHA256");

        // Base 64 encode the sig so its 8-bit clean 
        return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
    }
```

Signing with OpenSSL works, generates valid digital signature but signing with Cryptography lib generates invalid signature so my question is what I implemented wrong?

I tried to use different encoding but it did not help. Certificates are generated correctly.

It might by also useful to tell basic info about the .pem certificate:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC
```

Comment: I notice that the OpenSSL example is using SHA1 not SHA256. When you say that with the Microsoft library an invalid signature is generated, how did you verify that signature?

Comment: What certificate? I just see a private key?

Comment: @softwariness Payment gateway verified it.

Comment: @Maarten I've just posted the beginning of the certificate because I think there is no more useful info.

Comment: @softwariness  I read that OpenSSL uses some special type of SHA1 that is supported in SHA256 in Microsoft library. I also verify a response from payment gateway with public key and I use SHA256 that works fine.